# List files starting with a specific character

Tags: r

I have a folder which contains files of the following names `"5_45name.Rdata"`and `"15_45name.Rdata"`.

I would like to list only the ones starting with "5", in the example above this means that I would like to exclude `"15_45name.Rdata"`.

Using `list.files(pattern="5_*name.Rdata")`, however, will list both of these files.

Is there a way to tell list.files() that I want the filename to start with a specific character?

Comment: thanks! this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need to use the metacharacter (`^`) to specify the start of the string followed by the number 5.  So, it can a more specific pattern like below

```
list.files(pattern ="^5[0-9]*_[0-9]*name.Rdata")
```

Or concise if we are not concerned about the `_` and other numbers following it.

```
list.files(pattern = "^5.*name.Rdata")
```