# If statement for directory starting with specific character

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a script in which I call R and depending on the directory I specify I want it to carry out a different process. One directory starts with L and the other with S. I have numerous directories that either start with L or S and they all end differently.

I specify the directory in bash and run a script like so:

```
./script L_dir
```

or

```
./script S_dir
```

So within my R script I have it set up as such:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
img_dir <- args[1]
if(img_dir == "^L*"){
  do_process_1 
} else {
  do_process_2
}
```

Everything works fine except that no matter what directory I specify, the process called will always be do_process_2.

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240233/list-files-starting-with-a-specific-character) and tried to adapt it but can't get it to work.

Comment: `==` does not perform regex-analysis. I guess, this must always go into process_2 unless you call it with a directory named `^L*`. Have a look at the R functions `grep` and `substr`.

Comment: Try `if(grepl("^L*", img_dir)){...`. `grepl()` returns a logical value, so it will automatically answer the condition.

Comment: I'm still new to all of this so where do i put my do_process_1 ?

Comment: You just replace the if statement with LAPs if statement, and the rest remains the same

Comment: This doesn't work as it says unexpected token grepl with the red dots under the second grepl
`if(grepl("^L*", img_dir)){.... grepl()  do_process_1  } else {  do_process_2  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing my code to

```
if(grepl("^LM*", img_dir)){
  do_process_1
  } else {
  do_process_2
}
```

it worked. Be careful if you change it to the above and it still carries out process_2. This may be because what you are looking for, in my case ^L*, may also be in your second directory name i.e. dir_L = LMNOP, dir_S = STUVLJH. But once i specified ^LM* it did what i wanted it to do.